# How can i improve my search function ? PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here and i started coding in PHP and using MySQL.
I want to search multiple "keywords", for example "Intel i7 7700k" in table and I have no idea how to accomplish this.

My structure of my MySQL Table looks like this:
`id | brand | family | model | cores | threads` etc.
`1  | Intel | i7     | 7700k | 4     | 8` etc.

The following PHP search works, but only for one word.

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
  $search = $conn->escape_string($_GET['search']);

  $query = $conn->query("
    SELECT brand, family, model
    FROM cpus
    WHERE brand LIKE '%{$search}%'
    OR family LIKE '%{$search}%'
    OR model LIKE '%{$search}%'
  ");
```

I was trying to loop the array of words, but it doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
  $search = $conn->escape_string($_GET['search']);
  $words = explode(' ',$search);
  $searchout = foreach ($words as $word){
    "SELECT brand, family, model FROM cpus WHERE brand LIKE '%$word%' OR family LIKE '%$word%' OR model LIKE '%$word%'"
  }
  $query = $conn->query($search_out);

    echo "<div class='result-count'>Found " . $query->num_rows . " results.</div>";

    if($query->num_rows){
      while($r = $query->fetch_object()){

        echo "<div class='result'><a href='#'>" . $r->brand . $r->model . "</a></div>";
      }
    }
}
```

How can i make the search working on multiple words?
Like `"Intel i7 7700k" "7700k intel i7" "i7 7700k intel"` etc.

Here is my another try which also failed:

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
  $search = $conn->escape_string($_GET['search']);
  $words = explode(' ',$search);
  $words_count = count($words);
  $cpus_columns = ['brand','family','model'];
  print_r($cpus_columns);
  $mysql_where = "SELECT brand, family, model FROM cpus WHERE ".$cpus_columns[0]." LIKE ".$words[0];
  $mysql_loop = for ($i = 1; $i <= $words_count; $i++){
    " OR ".$cpus_columns[$i]." LIKE ".$words[$i]
  }
  $mysql_query = $mysql_where . $mysql_loop;
  $query = $conn->query($mysql_query);

    echo "<div class='result-count'>Found " . $query->num_rows . " results.</div>";

    if($query->num_rows){
      while($r = $query->fetch_object()){

        echo "<div class='result'><a href='#'>" . $r->brand . $r->model . "</a></div>";
      }
    }
}
```

I start slowly hating PHP and MySQL, 4 days and can't get it working this is just sad.

Comment: Please look into using prepared statements in your PHP code.  After this, look into using full text search for your MySQL query, as I think it could help here.

Comment: Your code is wrong (maybe just typo error). You have `$searchout = foreach...` and right after that `$query = $conn->query($search_out);` with a '_' sign. Did you try putting everything inside the `foreach($words as $word)` loop, then calling the query several times?

Comment: It seems so like i was calling the query several times, but how can i get the "finished result" of that "foreach loop" and add it to the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i make a searching for somethg 
in my case only for name ,but u can add more

```
$arry = array();
$arry = explode(" ",$POST["search"]);    

$query="SELECT * FROM tblfbaccban WHERE ";
for($c=0;$c<sizeof($arry);$c++)
{
    $query=$query."Name LIKE'%$arry[$c]%'";
    if($c<sizeof($arry)-1)
    {
        $query=$query." OR ";
    }
}
$sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH)) 
{
    echo $row["Name"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I used your code but did few other things, i get a 500 error.